# How can i configure mongo morgan in my express project?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, npm, morgan

I'm trying to use [mongo-morgan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongo-morgan). I use it like the original morgan package, but I don't get any response in terminal logs.

I have tried this (changing 'url' to my database url):

`app.use(mongoMorgan('url', 'dev'));`

and this (from the mongo-morgan repository):

```
app.use(mongoMorgan('url', 'combined', { collection: 'logs'}));
```

Comment: Do you get any error?? what is the behaviour of your script??

Comment: No one, I think that in the moment that I connect to my db, it should print something in my terminal but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

mongomorgan has an onConnect() function. If you want to be notified whenever you get a connection to the database, i think you should log the message in this function. It's signature is 
`function onConnect(error, mongoDb)`